# How can I turn glossy finish matte?

Tags: painting, repainting

I've just decorated my front room, but the skirting boards and cabinets are too glossy and I'm looking for a way to turn them matte.  Is there a product or method which I can use to remove the shine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used a matte varnish in the end :)

Answer (score 2):

Sanding with a very fine grit. And then possibly repainting with a matte finish if the results aren't good enough to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

I think steel wool would be easier to use.